# What does the $ mean in Linux?

Tags: linux, terminal

I have to explain what the code below means

What does the dollar bit mean?

```
 user@Linux-003 ~ $
```

Comment: This is just the prompt. See [What is the origin of the UNIX $ (dollar) prompt?](http://superuser.com/q/57575/204979) in [su] for more info.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For this particular case following code means:

Somebody with user name "user" has logged in to the machine with host name "Linux-003".

"~" - represent the home folder of the user, conventionally it would be /home/user/, where "user" is the user name can be anything like /home/johnsmith.

"$" - is just a sign of the shell prompt, means that shell is ready to accept commands, you can understand it as a separator after which, you can interact with a shell.
Can also be "#" which shows that root is the user who's session is going on.

Answer (score 5):

Although most people don't know this, it actually stands for - Swag.

(It actually means "normal user" or "non-root user")

`\#` would dictate a root user.

Comment: No, of course that's paraphrasing, but that's near enough what it suggests, non-root user would have been more accurate.

Comment: So what does the ~ mean?

Comment: I believe it's the user directory, if you type ~YOUR_USERNAME something should happen, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on a mac perchance? On my mac terminal it basically means ~ is my home directory and dollar means I can write a command after it. so it's user. your home directory. and then a symbol signifying if you can write commands or not. (There are instances where you might be in an editor where you have no $ sign meaning you cannot write commands)